# How to hide overflow on tables

Tags: html, css

This question has been asked several time on stackoverflow, however I was wondering if someone -perhaps you- doesn't have a unique solution to my problem.

I currently have an parent div that is of varying height and width whose contents are also of varying width and height. To vertically align the child div I have styled it's parent as `display: table;` and it as `display: table-cell;` and nested yet another div, as seen below:

```
<!-- css styling  -->
<style type="text/css">
.div-table {
display: table;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
 }

.div-cell {
display: table-cell;
padding: 10px;
vertical-align: middle;
 }

.div-alignedcontents {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
}
</style>

<!-- html  -->
<div class="div-table">
    <div class="div-cell">
        <div class="div-alignedcontents">
            <p>Some content that has a varying height and width!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the `overflow:hidden` property doesn't seem to work on tables, and `table-layout: fixed` property doesn't constrain vertical proportions/height. One solution would be to nest all the above html in yet another div and style that div with `overflow:hidden`, however I thought I might pick your brains for any suggestions first.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: did you try word-wrap ?

Comment: Nope, on which element do you propose?

Comment: td element or add padding. Tables are funny like that.

Comment: Nope, tried both. Note: Nested content is necessarily text.

Comment: hmm... are you displaying table data or trying to use a table as a display?

Comment: As a display, forms, images, text... vertically and horizontally aligning contents.

Comment: typically we don't use tables for that anymore. A div would be the best practice. It takes more elements to get a table up and running as opposed to a div. Is this like a proof of concept?

Comment: if you add a div in the td you can apply overflow to it and it should work.

Comment: No, for the app I am working on it is necessary. This is the best method for centering variable content within a variable container -without javascript.

Comment: Oh ok, can you add a div to the td and apply overflow?

Comment: There is already a div nested within .div-cell, and I have already tested overflow:hidden on it. O.o Does'nt work... Seems I have to to backtrack and add parent divs...

Comment: hmm... I'm at a loss if that didn't work. I haven't used a table for display in 5 yrs.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be defining `padding` for `.div-cell` in percentage and subtracting the same padding from the width of your `div-table`. Something like this:

```
.div-table {
    width: 95%
    height: 95%
}
.div-cell {
    padding: 2.5%
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qwPRn/)

Comment: The height of .div-table and .div-cell vary, so JavaScript would be needed to keep the proportion in check. If I understand you correctly.